# Gulp-hg task seems to finish before actually complete

Tags: gulp

I've got a task in gulp, using gulp-hg, as follow:

```
gulp.task('init',['clean'],function(){
    return hg.clone('https://myrepo','./deploy',{args:'--insecure'},function(error,stout){
        util.log(error);
    });
});
```

apparently gulp execute another task depending on 'init', before the command finish. Is something wrong in the way I'm using the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow one of the [async task patterns](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support):

1. Accept a callback
2. Return a stream
3. Return a promise

In your example, a callback might look like this:

```
gulp.task('init',['clean'],function(cb){
    hg.clone('https://myrepo','./deploy',{args:'--insecure'},function(error,stout){
        util.log(error);
        cb(error);
    });
});
```